# Publish from Visual Studio to a specific web site?

Tags: c#, deployment, clickonce

I have a C# project that I am developing with Visual Studio and am deploying with Click-Once. There's nothing fancy about that.

However, I'm wondering if it's possible to include the intended deployment path within a config file or something else? I know that the last deployed URL is kept in the history of the project, but what if I want to dynamically set this and have the Click Once deployment read from the project config file?

Comment: Just to clarify, this is not an ASP.NET project I want to deploy, it's actually a WPF project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the identity of a ClickOnce application is the URL from whence it is installed. So you can not install an application from one URL and then install it from another URL and have it work. The only way to modify the deployment provider URL is to change it in the deployment manifest (yourapp.application) and re-sign the manifest with the original certificate using Mage or MageUI.

We deploy our application to a DNS entry that points to a folder on our website. This way, if we want to move it, we can just re-point the DNs entry to a different IP address and not impact the deployment.

You can actually deploy your application with no url in it. When the user installs it, it will save the url it was installed from and use that as the deployment provider URL.

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish; more information might help me help you come up with a way to accomplish what you're trying to do if none of the above is helpful.

Comment: I understand your answer. But my question is more in relation to different builds. Let's say that I want to have my Debug build deploy to one URL for download and I want my Release to use another URL. So, the apps would maintain the identity, it's merely the initial URL deployment that would be handled dynamically.